# unable to start jupyter notebook: TypeError

Tags: jupyter-notebook

When running the command `jupyter notebook`, I am getting the following error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/local/bin/jupyter-notebook", line 6, in <module>
    from notebook.notebookapp import main
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages/notebook/notebookapp.py", line 47, in <module>
    from zmq.eventloop import ioloop
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages/zmq/eventloop/__init__.py", line 3, in <module>
    from zmq.eventloop.ioloop import IOLoop
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages/zmq/eventloop/ioloop.py", line 21, in <module>
    from tornado import ioloop
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages/tornado/ioloop.py", line 45, in <module>
    from tornado.concurrent import (
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages/tornado/concurrent.py", line 175, in <module>
    future: Union["futures.Future[_T]", "Future[_T]"], value: _T
  File "/usr/lib/python3.5/typing.py", line 552, in __getitem__
    dict(self.__dict__), parameters, _root=True)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.5/typing.py", line 512, in __new__
    for t2 in all_params - {t1} if not isinstance(t2, TypeVar)):
  File "/usr/lib/python3.5/typing.py", line 512, in <genexpr>
    for t2 in all_params - {t1} if not isinstance(t2, TypeVar)):
  File "/usr/lib/python3.5/typing.py", line 190, in __subclasscheck__
    self._eval_type(globalns, localns)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.5/typing.py", line 177, in _eval_type
    eval(self.__forward_code__, globalns, localns),
  File "<string>", line 1, in <module>
TypeError: 'type' object is not subscriptable
```

Im not using Anaconda. Clean python 3.5.2 and pip3.

Does any one know what the problem is?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Downgrading to tornado 5.1.1 will solve that problem.
As you are using pip3

```
sudo pip3 uninstall tornado
sudo pip3 install tornado==5.1.1
```